# Can we stop to add -o- prefix in css for opera browser

Tags: css, browser, webkit

Can we stop to add -o- prefix in css for opera browser or not. I ask this question because opera browser move to web-kit engine.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Opera supports certain -webkit- prefixes and will use these when applying styles as described [here](http://www.opera.com/docs/specs/presto2.12/css/aliases/).

But if you want to support older versions is better to use.

Comment: Thanks. It means we used -o- prefix as well.